# Can we consider the projection from $L_2$ to RKHS $H$?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, orthogonality, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be some domain. Let $k(x,y): \Omega^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a kernel on the domain and $H$ to be the RKHS induced by $k$. Here, I want to consider the projection from $L_2(\Omega)$ to $H$. For any given $f \in L_2(\Omega)$, can we define

$$f_{\mathrm{proj}} = \arg \min_{\tilde f \in H} || f - \tilde f ||^2_{L_2(\Omega)}$$

where $|| f ||_{L_2(\Omega)} = \sqrt{E[f^2(x)]}$ is the norm in $L_2(\Omega)$?

Also, is it true that residual is orthogonal to $H$? i.e.  given $f_{\mathrm{proj}}$,

$$\int_\Omega (f(x) - f_{\mathrm{proj}}(x))\tilde f(x) P(x) \mathrm{d}x = 0$$

for all $\tilde f \in H$?
I can easily see this is true when $k$ is a polynomial kernel, but can we generalize this result to an infinite dimensional kernel (such as a Gaussian kernel)? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Formally it should be $\arg \min_{\tilde f \in H} || f - i(\tilde f) ||^2_{L_2(\Omega,P)}$ right? Where $i: \mathcal{H} \to L_2(\Omega, P)$ is the canonical embedding, i.e. $i(\tilde f)$ is the equivalent class of functions such that $g = \tilde f$ $P-$a.e.

Comment: Then if you expand the norm and write a first order condition you get that any solution $\tilde f$ should satisfy $i^*i(\tilde f)  = i^*(f)$, where $i^*$ is the adjoint of $i$ and is an integral operator w.r.t $k$ from $L_2(\Omega, P)$ to $\mathcal{H}$. $i^*i$ is Trace class and is not invertible on an infinite dimensional RKHS, hence I do not think you can write $f_{proj}$.